# c# at a arbitrary or random time , make a function execute

Tags: c#

I want to make a function which has an alarm execute at the arbitrary time on everyday... I use c#.

I can not find proper method or code. I think I could use timer or rand method, but it happens regular time.

Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int i, k;
        int j;
        Console.WriteLine("가위는 0, 바위는 1, 보는 2 선택 => ");            
        string ReadValue = Console.ReadLine();
        j = Convert.ToInt32(ReadValue);
        k = new Random().Next() % 3;
        if(k == 0 && j == 1 || k == 1 && j == 2 || k == 2 && j == 0)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("플레이어 승! \n");
        }
        else if(k == j)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("무승부! \n");
        }
        else{
        Console.WriteLine("플레이어 패배! \n");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is *vague* one. There're many possible implementations depending on what you *actually want*. The simplest one, IMHO, is to wait:

```
private static Random random = new Random();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   while (true) 
   {
       // from 10 seconds up to 1 day;
       int timeToWait = random.Next(10, 86400) * 1000; 

       Thread.Sleep(timeToWait);

       Alarm();
    } 
} 

static void Alarm() 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Alarm!");
}
```

Comment: sorry for what i wrote... there is a robot that fix my writing.... that code isn't what i really mean... this stackoverflow site wants me to write the code ...so i just copy some code...

Comment: by the way ... the code that you wrote ... it happens every 10 seconds? for a day?

Comment: i am so shy for my knowledge ... i want to fine the way ... to make alarm cry ... random time...on everyday... i do not have code... i just about make a program... before making one... i want to make a kind of ...mold...

Comment: @apple fine: I've tried to implement as you've put it " an alarm execute at the arbitrary time on everyday". So the routine waits a random interval (which is from 10 seconds up to 1 day) and then goes off the alarm; then wait another random interval and so on.

Comment: oh ...that happens on random time... but why did you put 1000 after (10, 86400)?;;;

Comment: @apple fine: `Thread.Sleep` wants *milliseconds* as an argument; I generate just *seconds*; you can put `random.Next(10000, 86400000);` if you like

Comment: oh... ㅠㅠ  thank you for your kindness answers ...i can study a lot of knowledge which is very useful... !!! so!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! thank you!!!again

Comment: You are welcome! Next time, please, invest a bit more time to put your question to words.

Comment: i get your kindness advice ^^

Comment: @applefine If this answered your question, please don't forget to accept as answer by clicking the check-mark Button on the question. It's a way of saying thank you. http://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Comment: @Programmer did i do right? the mark has changed green

Comment: @applefine Yes, congrats. That's what you do if your question is answered and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the Random in the wrong way. You should have a `Random r = new Random();` outside a loop that is executing your method and inside the loop a `k=r.Next();`.

`Random(seed)` with the same seed always return the same value. You either have to do what I said above, or modify the seed every execution, but for this, you need a random value!. I recommend you to read the Random reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: sorry for what i wrote... there is a robot that fix my writing.... that code isn't what i really mean... this stackoverflow site wants me to write the code ...so i just copy some code... that has nothing to do with my question...